# removing \xa0, \n, \t from python string

Tags: python, string, unicode

I have a list item, that I've converted into a string:

```
[u'\n                      Door:\xa0Novum          \t      ']
```

I need to remove everything so that Im left with

```
Door:Novum
```

I have tried various methods:

```
string = string.replace("\xa0", "")
string.rstrip('\n')
string.translate(string.maketrans("\n\t", ""))
```

I am obviously doing something wrong, but can't figure out what

Comment: Strings are immutable.`strip` method won't change the original string.

Comment: So, are you getting an error message, or what?

Comment: No, just nothing happens

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to *store the return value*; strings are immutable so methods return a new string with the change applied.

You can translate for all those characters, but use the `unicode` form of the method:

```
toremove = dict.fromkeys((ord(c) for c in u'\xa0\n\t '))
outputstring = inputstring.translate(toremove)
```

I'm assuming you wanted to get rid of *spaces* as well.

Demo:

```
>>> inputstring = u'\n                      Door:\xa0Novum          \t      '
>>> toremove = dict.fromkeys((ord(c) for c in u'\xa0\n\t '))
>>> outputstring = inputstring.translate(toremove)
>>> outputstring
u'Door:Novum'
```

A better method still would be to use `str.split()`, then join again:

```
outputstring = u''.join(inputstring.split())
```

`\xa0`, spaces, tabs and newlines are all included in what `str.split()` will split on, as well as carriage returns.

Demo:

```
>>> u''.join(inputstring.split())
u'Door:Novum'
```

This is better because it is a *lot* faster for this job than using `str.translate()`!

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('inputstring.translate(toremove)', 'from __main__ import inputstring, toremove')
3.4527599811553955
>>> timeit.timeit('u"".join(inputstring.split())', 'from __main__ import inputstring')
0.5409181118011475
```